# Calling a method that created in helper method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created this helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyPlayer(this HtmlHelper helper, string mediafile, int height, int width)
{
    var player =
        @"<embed height=""{0}"" width=""{1}"" flashvars=""...""
                        allowfullscreen=""true""
                        quality=""high""
                        name="" src=""...""
                        type=""application/x-shockwave-flash"">";

    player = string.Format(player, height, width, mediafile);
    return new MvcHtmlString(player);
}
```

Now I want to show the video in Razor. So I call this helper in razor like this:

My View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.MyPlayer("ViedoCodeformediafileparameter", 400, 500)
```

**My question is:** In page source it just generates an **embed** tag. Should I use any player tag like video to play this video? If so, How should I use it in this case that I use helper method because currently it shows nothing?

Comment: Mediafile is not used in your function and the src is empty.

Comment: @ArDumez No. The helper is correct. It just an example to simplify my question. Don't worry about helper just please tell me Should I use any player tag like video to play this video? Also I sent ViedoCodeformediafileparameter to Mediafile.

Comment: If you use flash embeded test if your browser support flash else use tag video for the recent browser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943601/difference-between-embed-object-and-video-tags

Comment: Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Comment: So the question isn't about the helper, but what tag you should use?  I'm confused why the helper is included in the question, then.